# how to avoid Bootstrap Datepicker default date choosen automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I used `Bootstrap` `DatePicker` in a form, this is not a mandatory field. So whenever i submit a form without selecting the date on `Datepicker`. The default value like this `01-01-1970` only stored on `datebase`. I want to store like 0 instead of this value `01-01-1970`.

**I use Code like this**

```js
$('#dateRangePicker1').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  autoclose: true,
  minDate: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group input-group input-append date" id='dateRangePicker4'>
    <input type="text" id="cust_dob" class="form-control" name="date4" value="" placeholder="DOB" />
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Where is `dateRangePicker1` in your `html` ?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that by default, the bootstrap datepicker doesn't set the default value. You can check it here: [Sandbox](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox). You can open developer console and try

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker('getDate')
```

This will return null for you. If this is not set to be required, *null* will be sent through form.

My belief is what you have set in your database is the cause of this behaviour. I think you have set the type to the column to be DATETIME, (not null, too) which makes the database to set in the default date, which is 01-01-1970 (the start of Unix timestamp). If this is the case, you can set the column type to be varchar, set the value to be some common format (YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss is one of them). On client side, you can use some popular datetime library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the time or generate dateTime string to save to database.

Comment: I set Column type is VARCHAR(50), and SET Default Value is Null

Comment: @NaveenJ please provide me with your html setup. Create jsfiddle, maybe?